# Where is method table stored in C#?

Tags: c#

I’m studying .NET architecture, but I have no idea where Method Table is stored.
.NET Assembly contains Manifest, Type metadata and CIL code.
Is method table in Type metadata?
Or is in heap?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to know. It's built as types are loaded. Initially it points to stubs that get changed as the JIT compiler compiles methods on demand. It's obviously in memory and definitely not in the managed heap. This is a bit of an overview of the process https://dev.to/mattwarren/how-does-net-jit-a-method-also-featuring-tiered-compilation-4if. Don't be surprised if your question closes, it's not really a Stackoverflow question

Comment: It's on the moon, that's all you really need to know. You make a number of assumptions here: "where Method Table is stored" The method table might not even exist in the way you think, as parts of it could be optimized away, or another dispatch method might be used. "Is method table in Type metadata? Or is in heap?" you say these as if they were mutually exclusive and the only options. They are not: the metadata may or may not be on the heap anyway, there may not be a heap (other memory models exist in some implementations), there may be other places that data is stored.

Comment: The place to look for this kind of thing if you really want to understand the nitty gritty, get a copy of Jeff Richter's "CLR via C#"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from 20+ year old memory. I knew most of this at one time.

When the loader first decides it needs a type, it loads the appropriate assembly/module into a memory mapped file in (native) memory.

Then it reads the type metadata via the manifest and the rest of the metadata. At that point, it builds the method table (and other type-specific goop). It's in a native memory segment somewhere.

Initially, the method table contains a stub for each method. The stub, when invoked, will get the JIT compiler to compile the IL (resident in the assembly's memory mapped file) into native code (resident in a native memory segment). The methods get JIT compiled one by one as they are called.

Somewhere during that process, if the type has a static constructor, it will be called (the spec says that this will happen before any code referencing the type is run - I believe the exact time has changed once).

The point I'm trying to make is that "where" it resides is unimportant; it's its behavior that is important.

Comment: The example I like to use is "Your memory is stored on the moon, which is made of cheese, and the stack is a pile of pizza boxes in a pizza shop, and implemented with pen and paper markings on the boxes. Why do you care?"

Comment: @Charlieface absolutely nothing wrong with seeking to understand the internals of the CLR.

Comment: @async True, but often these questions come across in a way that seems to imply it should make a difference to you, when it very rarely does. The final line of this answer is clear this: *The point I'm trying to make is that "where" it resides is unimportant; it's its behavior that is important.*

Comment: Those are just your assumptions. I can guarantee that you are not the only one interested in low level details. Honestly it's irrelevant why people ask these questions. You don't get to decide what people "need" to know. Remember that this is SO and the reach of the answer above goes beyond the intentions of the OP. @Flydog57 was very generous with his time and knowledge and that's a far more valuable contribution.